# Swiping left on the touchpad opens the photo search. How do I disable this?

Tags: unity, 14.04, touchpad, trackpad

It's almost random, but most of the time, if I swipe from right to left on the touchpad of my keyboard, it opens the photo search.  I have not been able to locate any setting/tweak that explains this or would disable it.

Comment: I couldn't find an answer for this question, and there seems to be nothing similar that could explain how to disable this.

Answer (score 4):

I am guessing this was a problem with a k400 or k400r wireless keyboard (or some other logitech equivalent). If so I finally found and answer

Fn + Right Click -> Enables/Disables Gestures.
Fn + Left Click -> Enables/Disables Tap to click.

Sorry for digging up such an old thread, but I have hit this question on AskUbuntu many times while trying to solve this problem over the years, so thought I would at east record the answer for myself.

Comment: The problem with your answer is that you have to do the trick each time you turn the device on to disable edge gestures of K400r.

Comment: K400 does not have edge gestures, but K400r does: https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023253174

Comment: Holy cow, this (Fn+RightClick) even works on ChromeOS!

Answer (score 1):

Logitech K400r sends Win/Super + C shortcut when you swipe from the right edge of the touchpad to left, when edge gestures are enabled (see the other answer). So you could possibly override the binding of that particular keyboard shortcut to another command, like `sh -c :` that does nothing but waste some resources for a short time. Or maybe you could even just remove that keybinding. The method for those depends on the desktop environment you use, but I don't go into more details in this answer. You may find an answer on how it can be done in Unity elsewhere.

K400r has also some other edge gestures possibly issuing other keyboard shortcuts, but I don't know which shortcuts it could issue. See here for the edge gestures: https://www.logitech.com/assets/42364/8/k400-quick-start-guide.pdf